# Does a .net core library for english lemmatization exist? If not where should someone begin in order to write a lemmatization algorithm?

Tags: .net-core, lemmatization

I have been working on a research application as part of a research team in order to determine relationships between several documents. The documents are currently parsed from pdf, stop words are removed, and the remaining text is run through the Porter stemming algorithm. This method is proving to be not as accurate as our research had hoped, and I have been tasked with finding a library in order to handle the lemmatization of the text. I have been so far unable to locate a .net core library able to assist in lemmatization. I want to know if such a library exists or in the case no such library exists, how would I begin to devise an algorithm for lemmatization of english words?

Comment: I'm not sure what exists for .net but if you're willing to write a little code, you can copy the `lemma_lu.csv` file from [lemminflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect/tree/master/lemminflect/resources) and create a look-up table from it.  If a word isn't in the lookup, then revert to using the stemmer.  I think SpaCy also has some lookup tables too.